# Change div min-height according to content, before content loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation like this:

A parent  has a few other divs inside and a background image (set via CSS). One of the child divs (class "slow-subtitle) appears when the user scrolls down and it contains text.

Now, when the child div appears, the parent div changes its height accordingly, but sometimes the background image jumps because of the new height of the div. I solved the issue by setting the parent div min-height to a high value which covers most situations (I have several pages with this code) but it leaves a big empty gap when the content of child div is short.

I would like to calculate the height of the parent div BEFORE, so that when the child div loads, nothing jumps and the page renders correctly.

Here's my code

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid slow-title-box">    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">         
        <h1 class="h1-bg">Title</h1>
        <div class="slow-subtitle">
            <h4>Text</h4>
            <p>More text</p>    
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".slow-subtitle,").hide();
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 50) {
    $('.slow-subtitle').fadeIn(700);
  } else {
    $('.slow-subtitle').fadeOut(700);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you are starting the page with the space for the content, why hide it at all?  Or if you don't want the background image to jump, why not use an effect like slide down, so the background will slide down as the content shows.  Otherwise, just use opacity 0 and then the content will keep it's space then you can animate the opacity to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` set item to `display:none`, thats why you are facing the background image jump issue.

Instead of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, try to add and remove a class and use `opacity`...It will also give you the fade effect

```
$(".slow-subtitle").addClass("hidden");
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 50) {
    $('.slow-subtitle').removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $('.slow-subtitle').addClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.slow-subtitle {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This solution works flawlessly, thank you! I could have thought about it, I will get there eventually

Answer (score 0):

I think with true/false you can do this

```
$(".slow-subtitle").hide();
var slowsubtitle_hide = true;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 50 && slowsubtitle_hide == true) {
    slowsubtitle_hide = false;
    $('.slow-subtitle').stop().fadeIn(700);
  } else if (y < 50 && slowsubtitle_hide == false){
    slowsubtitle_hide = true;
    $('.slow-subtitle').stop().fadeOut(700);
  }
});
```